# Django ORM distinct query where order is done by annotated field and you need distinct('id')

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-orm

Merchant has places. Places have a location coordinates. I need to return a list of **UNIQUE** merchants through API call (DRF) filtered by distances of proximity to any place they have associated and return back distance value from the closest place. Right now I get duplicates (i.e. merchant gets returned multiple times if there are several places of the merchant in proximity).

If I try to have `annotate(distance=...).distinct('pk')` I get error message

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: 
    SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
    LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (&quot;merchants_merchan
```

If I add `.order_by('pk')` I can then use `.distinct('pk')`, but then I can't sort returning queryset by distance.

Here is what I have done so far:

#### Queryset

```
class MerchantQuerySet(models.QuerySet):    
    def nearby(self, latitude, longitude, proximity=None):
        """Get nearby Merchants.

        Custom queryset method for getting merchants associated with
        nearby places.

        Returns:
            A queryset of ``Merchant`` objects.

        """
        point = Point(latitude, longitude)

        # we query for location nearby for places first and then
        # annotate with distance to the same place
        return self.filter(
            places__location__distance_lte=(point, D(ft=proximity))).\
            annotate(distance=Distance(
                'places__location', point)).distinct()
```

#### Models

```
class Merchant(TimeStampedModel):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Name'))
    description = models.TextField(
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('Description'),
    )
    logo = imagekitmodels.ProcessedImageField(
        max_length=512,
        upload_to=get_upload_path_for_model,
        processors=[ResizeToFill(300, 300)],
        format='PNG',
        options={'quality': 100},
        editable=True,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('Company logo'),
        help_text=_('Image will be resized to 300x300px.')
    )
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(
        'categories.Category',
        blank=True,
        related_name='merchants',
        verbose_name=_('Categories'),
    )
    address = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name=_('Address'))
    contact = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('Contact phone'),
    )
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, verbose_name=_('Site URL'))
    social_urls = ArrayField(
        models.URLField(blank=True),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=_('Social URLs'),
    )
    budget_tips = models.TextField(
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('Budget tips'),
        help_text=_('Recommendations to determine merchant budget.'),
    )

    objects = query.MerchantQuerySet.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Merchant')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Merchants')


class Place(TimeStampedModel):

    id = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        primary_key=True,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name=_('ID'),
        help_text=_('Forsquare ID of the venue.'),
    )
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(
        'merchants.Merchant',
        related_name='places',
        verbose_name=_('Merchant'),
        help_text=_('Merchant, business owner.'),
    )
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(
        'categories.Category',
        blank=True,
        related_name='places',
        verbose_name=_('Categories'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('Name')
    )
    address = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name=_('Address'))
    contact = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_('Contact phone')
    )
    location = PointField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('Location'))

    objects = PlaceQuerySet.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Place')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Places')
```

#### DRF View

```
class MerchantViewSet(

            mixins.ListModelMixin,
            mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
            favorites_api_mixins.UserFavoritesMixin,
            viewsets.GenericViewSet,
    ):

        queryset = models.Merchant.objects.all()
        serializer_class = serializers.MerchantSerializer
        filter_backends = (MerchantOrderingFilter,
                           filters.DjangoFilterBackend,
                           filters.SearchFilter,
                           utils_filters.LocationDistanceFilter)

        ordering_fields = ('name', 'created', 'distance')
        ordering = ('-created')
        search_fields = ('name',)
```

#### utils_filters.LocationDistanceFilter

```
class LocationDistanceFilter(BaseFilterBackend):
    """Location distance filter.

    Class for filtering objects by distance. Takes three GET params ``lat``,
    ``long`` and ``dist``:

        .../?dist=300&lat=55.56&long=98.01

    """
    dist_param = 'dist'

    def get_filter_point(self, request):
        """Get filter point.

        Get point for filtering by distance to this point.

        Args:
            request (Request): A ``Request`` object.

        Returns:
            A ``Point`` object or None.

        Raises:
            Parse error if point is invalid.

        """
        latitude = request.query_params.get('lat')
        longitude = request.query_params.get('long')

        if latitude and longitude:
            try:
                latitude = float(latitude)
                longitude = float(longitude)
            except ValueError:
                raise ParseError(
                    'Invalid geometry string supplied for '
                    'latitude or longitude'
                )

            return Point(latitude, longitude)

        else:
            return None

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        """Filter queryset.

        Filter queryset by ``lat``, ``long`` and ``dist` params. Queryset
        should have method ``nearby``.

        Args:
            request (Request): A ``Request`` object.
            queryset (QuerySet): A ``QuerySet`` object.
            view (ViewSet): Current API view instance.

        Returns:
            A query set of objects filtered by latitude, longitude
            and distance.

        """
        distance = request.query_params.get(self.dist_param)
        point = self.get_filter_point(request)

        if not point:
            return queryset

        return queryset.nearby(
            latitude=point.x,
            longitude=point.y,
            proximity=distance,
        )
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `.distinct()` only, i.e. without the `'pk'` argument.

Comment: Hey, @DmitrySemenov I was wondering, was my answer helpful

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [`distinct()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) documentation (as @Todor suggests), you will find this:

> Any fields used in an `order_by()` call are included in the `SQL SELECT` columns. This can sometimes lead to unexpected results when used in conjunction with `distinct()`. If you order by fields from a related model, those fields will be added to the selected columns and they may make otherwise duplicate rows appear to be distinct. Since the extra columns don’t appear in the returned results (they are only there to support ordering), it sometimes looks like non-distinct results are being returned.

So whatever you do, do it with that in mind.

---

Let's try to work around that:

`annotate(distance=...)` creates a column named `distance` which you can use to sort your query. You need distinct merchants which can be assured by distinct `pk`s:

```
...annotate(distance=...).order_by('pk', 'distance').distinct('pk')
```

This will order your queryset first by `pk` then by `distance` and finally it will return only merchants with distinct `pk`.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar task, for me helped
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24218#comment:11

So i have model `Listing` + model `ListingAddress` (many for one `Listing`) + point. the task was to get distinct list of `Listings` ordered by closest `ListingAddress` to the point. Here is my code:

```
orm_request = ListingAddress.objects.filter(
    loc__distance_lte=(point, D(m=search_distance)),
    **make_category_filter(category_id),
).annotate(
    distance=Distance('loc', point)
)

closest_addresses = [rec['pk'] for rec in orm_request.order_by(
    'listing_id',
    'distance',
).distinct(
    'listing_id',
).values('pk')]

final_request = orm_request.filter(
    pk__in=subquery,
).order_by(
   'distance',
).select_related(
    'listing',
)
```